# What is the maximum data/speed transfer between 2 applications on the same computer

Tags: windows, delphi, indy

I have a client/server application written in delphiXe2 using Indy TIdTCPServer and TIdTCPClient that communicates with each other on the same computer using TCP address 127.0.0.1

When i use about 1 megs per second(8 Megabit) of data everything works fine.

However when set my data at higher speed like 20megs/sec (160 Megabit), it slow down and start to behave weirdly.

Is that an usual behavior for that speed? 
Also i can't seem to find any benchmark or information of what is the maximum data transfer speed between 2 local application.

Regards

Comment: BTW, how are you measuring bandwidth? Are you counting the bytes as you send or receive them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perform a bandwidth test. This is what I use (I have attached the relevant server and client code). FWIW, I get around 500Mbps maximum, although there is no way I could process data that fast.

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  lData: TByteDynArray;
  lCaption: string;
  lMbps: Real;
  lLen: Integer;
begin
  AContext.Connection.IoHandler.CheckForDataOnSource;
  SetLength(lData, 0);
  AContext.Connection.IoHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(TIdBytes(lData),
                                     AContext.Connection.IoHandler.InputBuffer.Size);
  lLen := Length(lData);
  if lLen > 0 then begin
    if FStartTime = 0 then begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss.zzz', CsiNow) +': Started test');
      FStartTime := CsiNow;
    end;
    Inc(FBytesReceived, lLen);
    lCaption := 'MBits Received: ' + CsiPadFloat(FBytesReceived * 1.0 / 125000, 3, 1);
    if lCaption <> FLastCaption  then begin
      Label1.Caption := lCaption;
      FLastCaption := lCaption;
    end;
    if FBytesReceived >= 12500000 then begin
      FStopTime := CsiNow;
      lMbps := 100000 / MilliSecondsBetween(FStopTime, FStartTime);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss.zzz', CsiNow) +
                      ': Finished test (' + CsiPadFloat(lMbps, 3, 1) + ' Mbps)');
      FBytesReceived := 0;
      FStartTime := 0;
    end
  end;

  CsiSleep(0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lData: TByteDynArray;
  lIndex: Integer;
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Host := Edit1.Text;
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;
  try
    SetLength(lData, 125000);
    for lIndex := 1 to 125000 do
      lData[lIndex - 1] := Ord('a');
    for lIndex := 1 to 100 do
      IdTCPClient1.IoHandler.Write(TIdBytes(lData));
  finally
    IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i'm going to benchmark it manually and find the limit this way.

Answer (score 2):

If you're (ab)using TCP/IP as a means to do IPC between processes that are designed to operate on the same machine, you will run into limits like these. By using TCP/IP, especially a local connection, all data is fragmented and pushed through the packet switching system that is TCP.  If this is the case you should look into one of these:

- Named or unnamed pipes
- Virtual memory mapping
- Passing WM_DATA messages around
- COM
- (feel free to add more of you find they deserve to get listed here)

Comment: Actually given that Indy can manage 500Mbps over TCP it is fairly obvious that TCP is not the problem. I would like to know what sort of applications need more than 500Mbps bandwidth between them! The problem is likely to be that the data cannot be processed any faster, not that the comms channel is the limiting factor.

Comment: @Misha, someone said `"640kb ought to be enough for anybody."`. Imagining an application that needs 500Mbps is not particularly difficult (especially given I've got two Gbps network cards in my PC, with one of them having a straight cable to a server, no switch, just maximum speed and low latency - and I might be able to use more)

Comment: PS Round trip time is the limiting factor in most TCP comms because of the TCP window size (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_tuning). The way to get better performance is to use multiple TCP connections because each one has a limiting throughput.

Comment: @Misha "Actually given that Indy can manage 500Mbps over TCP" I've read Indy documentation and i didn't find anywhere that information, but that is exactly the documentation i am looking for, if you could point it out it would be nice.

Comment: @Stijn Sanders I'm using TCP IP for my application because for now it is on the same computer, but in the near future it could be on 2 computers.

Comment: @Chadak, that was my test results

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to reproduce the issue, it is very hard to find out the problem.

IP communication is very stable locally (all data remains in memory, in OS buffers) - and 20 MB/s is nothing for a bandwidth speed on nowadays HW/SW.

I guess the issue is in your code, or you reached (multi-thread?) limitations of Delphi, and got contusion when handling the data.

Of course, did you try to disable your AntiVirus packet inspection? Some of them are slowing down the IP traffic a lot when inspecting the IP packets (even if it is not HTTP), and it results in such random IP traffic jam.